# Performing one hot encoding on two columns of string data

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, scikit-learn, decision-tree, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to predict 'Full_Time_Home_Goals'

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import os
import xlrd
import datetime
import numpy as np

# Set option to display all the rows and columns in the dataset. If there are more rows, adjust number accordingly.
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

# Pandas needs you to define the column as date before its imported and then call the column and define as a date
# hence this step.
date_col = ['Date']
df = pd.read_csv(
    r'C:\Users\harsh\Documents\My Dream\Desktop\Machine Learning\Attempt1\Historical Data\Concat_Cleaned.csv'
    , parse_dates=date_col, skiprows=0, low_memory=False)

# Converting/defining the columns
# Before you define column types, you need to fill all NaN with a value. We will be reconverting them later
df = df.fillna(101)
# Defining column types
convert_dict = {'League_Division': str,
                'HomeTeam': str,
                'AwayTeam': str,
                'Full_Time_Home_Goals': int,
                'Full_Time_Away_Goals': int,
                'Full_Time_Result': str,
                'Half_Time_Home_Goals': int,
                'Half_Time_Away_Goals': int,
                'Half_Time_Result': str,
                'Attendance': int,
                'Referee': str,
                'Home_Team_Shots': int,
                'Away_Team_Shots': int,
                'Home_Team_Shots_on_Target': int,
                'Away_Team_Shots_on_Target': int,
                'Home_Team_Hit_Woodwork': int,
                'Away_Team_Hit_Woodwork': int,
                'Home_Team_Corners': int,
                'Away_Team_Corners': int,
                'Home_Team_Fouls': int,
                'Away_Team_Fouls': int,
                'Home_Offsides': int,
                'Away_Offsides': int,
                'Home_Team_Yellow_Cards': int,
                'Away_Team_Yellow_Cards': int,
                'Home_Team_Red_Cards': int,
                'Away_Team_Red_Cards': int,
                'Home_Team_Bookings_Points': float,
                'Away_Team_Bookings_Points': float,
                }

df = df.astype(convert_dict)

# Reverting the replace values step to get original dataframe and with the defined filetypes
df = df.replace('101', np.NAN, regex=True)
df = df.replace(101, np.NAN, regex=True)

# Exploration
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

# Clean dataset by dropping null rows
data = df.dropna(axis=0)

# Column that you want to predict = y
y = df.Full_Time_Home_Goals

# Columns that are inputted into the model to make predictions (dependants), Cannot be column y
features = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'Full_Time_Away_Goals', 'Full_Time_Result']
# Create X
X = df[features]

# Split into validation and training data
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

# Specify Model
soccer_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)

# Fit Model
soccer_model.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

I am getting an error fitting to the model

```
# Fit Model
soccer_model.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Throws me an error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: "Nott'm Forest"

How can I solve this and run the model to get the output? I tried to follow a few examples but I am unable to progress.

You can fine the example concat_cleaned file [here](https://filebin.net/tom8hvsjoxms1tqh)

Comment: Machine learning model cannot handle string data. You have various columns specified as a string.

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and should *not* be posted here, as it just creates uneccessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to transform your categorical data into numerical data. For that, you could use the OneHotEncoder:

```
import os
import xlrd
import datetime
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Set option to display all the rows and columns in the dataset. If there are more rows, adjust number accordingly.
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

# Pandas needs you to define the column as date before its imported and then call the column and define as a date
# hence this step.
date_col = ['Date']
df = pd.read_csv(
    r'Concat_Cleaned_Example.csv'
    , parse_dates=date_col, skiprows=0, low_memory=False)

# Converting/defining the columns
# Before you define column types, you need to fill all NaN with a value. We will be reconverting them later
df = df.fillna(101)
# Defining column types
convert_dict = {'League_Division': str,
                'HomeTeam': str,
                'AwayTeam': str,
                'Full_Time_Home_Goals': int,
                'Full_Time_Away_Goals': int,
                'Full_Time_Result': str,
                'Half_Time_Home_Goals': int,
                'Half_Time_Away_Goals': int,
                'Half_Time_Result': str,
                'Attendance': int,
                'Referee': str,
                'Home_Team_Shots': int,
                'Away_Team_Shots': int,
                'Home_Team_Shots_on_Target': int,
                'Away_Team_Shots_on_Target': int,
                'Home_Team_Hit_Woodwork': int,
                'Away_Team_Hit_Woodwork': int,
                'Home_Team_Corners': int,
                'Away_Team_Corners': int,
                'Home_Team_Fouls': int,
                'Away_Team_Fouls': int,
                'Home_Offsides': int,
                'Away_Offsides': int,
                'Home_Team_Yellow_Cards': int,
                'Away_Team_Yellow_Cards': int,
                'Home_Team_Red_Cards': int,
                'Away_Team_Red_Cards': int,
                'Home_Team_Bookings_Points': float,
                'Away_Team_Bookings_Points': float,
                }

df = df.astype(convert_dict)

# Reverting the replace values step to get original dataframe and with the defined filetypes
df = df.replace('101', np.NAN, regex=True)
df = df.replace(101, np.NAN, regex=True)

# Clean dataset by dropping null rows
data = df.dropna(axis=0)

# Column that you want to predict = y
y = df.Full_Time_Home_Goals

# Columns that are inputted into the model to make predictions (dependants), Cannot be column y
features = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'Full_Time_Away_Goals', 'Full_Time_Result']
# Create X
X = df[features]

# Split into validation and training data
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

# Specify Model
soccer_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)

# Define and train OneHotEncoder to transform numerical data to a numeric array
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(train_X)

transformed_train_X = enc.transform(train_X)

# Fit Model
soccer_model.fit(transformed_train_X, train_y)
```

That way your data, for instance `(Man United,Newcastle,0,H)` would be encoded as

```
(0, 14) 1.0
(0, 35) 1.0
(0, 43) 1.0
(0, 50) 1.0
```

You can have a look at it for any data point to verify that it is correctly encoded, by using:

```
entry_id = 1

print(transformed_train_X[entry_id])

for i in range(0,transformed_train_X[0].shape[1]):
  if(transformed_train_X[entry_id,i]==1.0):
    print(enc.get_feature_names()[i])
```

Output:

```
  (0, 14)   1.0
  (0, 35)   1.0
  (0, 43)   1.0
  (0, 50)   1.0
x0_Man United
x1_Newcastle
x2_0
x3_H
```

Comment: Thats great Kim, When I go on to make validations and calculate MAE, I am getting a string error convering string to float.
`# Make validation predictions and calculate mean absolute error
val_predictions = soccer_model.predict(val_X)
val_mae = mean_absolute_error(val_predictions, val_y)
print("Validation MAE when not specifying max_leaf_nodes : {:,.0f}".format(val_mae))`
`Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Wolves'`
How would I go ahead with this?

Comment: This is a new problem, right? Can you please open up a new question and add your code with the error message there? It is easier to read and understand and other people can help you with that problem then as well.